# PHP / connection to Sphinx requires username / password

Tags: php, mysql, network-programming, sphinx

I am currently trying to connect to Sphinx via PDO or MySqli connector in order to use SphinxQL, however, although Sphinx has no username/password settings and I should be able to connect without the use of such, I get a user/pass error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

My connection try is as follows (mysqli in this case:)

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '', '9306');
```

localhost above works with Mysql, I also tried 127.0.0.1 without success (this gave me a connection refused error).

My sphinx conf looks as follows:

```
listen          = 9306:mysql41
```

searchd is running, and connection via shell works as it should:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# mysql -h0 -P 9306
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1 Server version: 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
```

As you can see above, I use Sphinx v.2.2.11

Just in case, I also re-checked the port assignments:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1475/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21599/searchd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4013/mysqld
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. For me 'localhost' doesn't work, '127.0.0.1' works fine (in particular mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', '', '', '', '9314') works fine). The port can be both a string and an integer. Just in case HY000/1045 is a mysql error, not Sphinx'.

Comment: Hi @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen. I am also still trying to figure out the issue. I have just started a test server instance on my hosting provider, and there it works as expected. I am beginning to think that this may be vagrant - related, as I am working on a windows host. I will try to reinstall Sphinx and see what happens, as I am out of any other options / ideas.

Comment: ... which made no difference at all :) still the same problem.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch what a coincidence )) a found this question because couldn't connect to my Manticore Server from PHP-PDO and your suggestion worked! If you're from Manticore Team probably you should mention this in your official docs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird things happen sometimes, without a plausible explanation. As mentioned, I am using vagrant (Centos 7.5) on a windows 10 host. The connection would not work no matter what. After putting it to rest for the day, my PC went to "sleep" mode. The next day, after revoking the system everything worked fine. What can I say ¯_(ツ)_/¯ . Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party, but I had the same issue and I have the solution :)

Instead of

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '', '9306');
```

use it this way

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost:9306', '', '', '');
```

And it will most likely work :)

I had the same issue on Sphinx Search 3.3.1, with mysql 8.0.
The above solved my issue.